# PHP echo table and its css

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I really need your help. I am trying to echo a table from my database but it first of all comes with my table names from the database which I don't want and also the css is weird. I would like my table to have a different heading in each column then the data displayed below the corresponding column header in a uniform manna.

the php code is here

```
    <div id="content-1">
        <div>
            <?php 

                $table = 'std_details';
                // sending query for table
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");

                if (!$result) {

                    die ("Query to show fields from table failed");

                }

                $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

                echo "<h1>All Students</h1>";
                echo "<table border='2' class='gridtable'><tr>";

                // printing table headers
                for ($i=0; $i < $fields_num; $i++) { 

                    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
                    echo "<td>{$field->name}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";

                }

                echo "</tr>\n";

                // printing table rows
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

                    echo "<tr>";

                    // $row is array.... foreach( .. ) puts every element
                    // of $row to $cell variable
                    foreach ($row as $cell) {

                        echo "<td>&nbsp;\t$cell</td>";

                    }
                    echo "</tr>\n";
                }

                mysql_free_result($result)
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the table css is

```
    table.gridtable {
        font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#333333;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #666666;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.gridtable th {
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #666666;
        background-color: #dedede;
    }
    table.gridtable td {
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #666666;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Thanks guys. I really need help!

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the css is weird". And we can't see your database, so we don't know what comes out of it and what to replace it with! Also, mysqli is better than mysql, which is deprecated. And you have SQL injection and even HTML injection.

Comment: If you want separate heading then don't pull from database. Keep you column heading static and load data from database

Comment: this is the image for my database @MrLister

Comment: Please note that `mysql` is not supported anymore. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: how can I use PDO or mysqli? am new yo databases. I just want to finish this then i start something new. Please help me and I use PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant understand why you are using mysql instead of mysqli any way this may help you

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <style>
      table.gridtable {
        font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#333333;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #666666;
        border-collapse: collapse;
       }
      table.gridtable th {
         border-width: 1px;
         padding: 8px;
         border-style: solid;
         border-color: #666666;
         background-color: #dedede;
       }
     table.gridtable td {
         border-width: 1px;
         padding: 8px;
         border-style: solid;
         border-color: #666666;
         background-color: #ffffff;
       }

    </style>
  <!--- uncomment these line if you are loading css from external file --->
  <!--- <link href="Your css file" rel="stylesheet"> --->
  </head>
<div id="content-1">
      <div>
           <?php 

            $table = 'std_details';
            // sending query for table
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");

                if (!$result) {

                  die ("Query to show fields from table failed");

                }

               $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

               echo "<h1>All Students</h1>";
               echo "<table border='2' class='gridtable'><tr>";

               // printing table headers
               for ($i=0; $i < $fields_num; $i++) { 

                $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
                echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";

            }

            echo "</tr>";

            // printing table rows
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

                echo "<tr>";

                // $row is array.... foreach( .. ) puts every element
                // of $row to $cell variable
                foreach ($row as $cell) {

                    echo "<td>&nbsp;\t$cell</td>";

                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

            mysql_free_result($result)
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I get to use mysqli? I have never used it. What's the difference? @GULIM

Comment: because mysql is deprecated just google for it , the only difference is the syntax

Answer (score 1):

For the tablename in field name you can use a simply `sustr($field->name, strlen ( $fieldName ........))` 
For the header use `<th>` and not `<td>` and don't use tab for cells value.
try like this

```
// printing table headers
            for ($i=0; $i < $fields_num; $i++) { 





                $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);

              // eliminate the tablename
              $name = substr($field->name, strlen ( $fieldName ) - strlen('yourTableName),strlen ( $fieldName ) -1  )
                // echo the header th
                echo "<th>{$name}&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>";

            }

            echo "</tr>\n";

            // printing table rows
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

                echo "<tr>";

                // $row is array.... foreach( .. ) puts every element
                // of $row to $cell variable
                foreach ($row as $cell) {

                    // echo the cell td
                    echo "<td>$cell</td>";

                }
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
```

Comment: yes is substr. (the basic php str function) i have update the answer

Comment: so how does PDO or mysqli come in?

Comment: If I may ask, do I have to replace '$fieldName' with the heading I want for that specific column?